# Error accessing categories in backend

Tags: magento2, category, backend, migration, magento-2.1.2

When I try to access "Categories" in backend, I receive an error.

The error is:

> Attribute with attributeCode "umm_dd_block_top" does not exist.

In the attributes list and the attributsets, the named code is really not existing.

It´s a Magento version 2.1.2, migrated from 1.9.3, including attributes - so maybe it is a standard attribute which was overridden by migration process?

Any advice would be appreciated.

The errorlog

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Attribute with attributeCode "umm_dd_block_top" does not exist.
#0 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/AttributeRepository.php(64): Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository->get('catalog_categor...', 'umm_dd_block_to...')
#1 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Category/Form/Element/Wysiwyg.php(59): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\AttributeRepository->get('umm_dd_block_to...')
#2 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory), Object(Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Backend\Helper\Data), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\AttributeRepository), Array, Array, Array)
#3 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)
#4 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)
#5 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(212): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)
#6 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Field.php(83): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('umm_dd_block_to...', 'wysiwyg', Array)
#7 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(148): Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field->prepare()
#8 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field))
#9 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset))
#10 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(126): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form))
#11 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'category_form', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#12 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#13 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#14 MAGEROOT/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#15 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#16 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#17 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#18 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#19 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#20 MAGEROOT/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#21 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')
#22 MAGEROOT/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#23 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php(102): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#24 MAGEROOT/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit->execute()
#25 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->execute()
#26 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#29 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#30 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#33 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 MAGEROOT/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#36 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#39 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#40 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'infortis_cgen_m...')
#43 MAGEROOT/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 MAGEROOT/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#46 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 MAGEROOT/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#48 MAGEROOT/index.php(49): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#49 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have delete some module recently but attribute from it remains.
go to Manage Attributes in backend and delete "umm_dd_block_top"
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I got it by myself by grep command and searching inside the app/* folder

`umm_dd_block_top` stands for Ultra-Mega-Menu, it seems that the attribute should have been installed via `/Setup/InstallData.php`, it should have create a catalog attribute with this name, but it did not in my case - so the error appears.

Create it by yourself or inspect the server error logs.
It could to be a server issue, if other module´s installer also not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the module **Infortis/Cgen**. Is it work?